# Obtain reference to existing browser window

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm 99% sure that the answer to my question will be no but just in case...

Use case:

1. Webpage A opens a new window B with JavaScript (same domain)
2. The user refreshes A or navigates away and then returns
3. The user clicks on a link in page A which should close B

This works fine by holding on to the window reference as long as the user does not refresh and navigates away from A (step 2).

Is there any (exotic or not) way to re-obtain the reference to the previously opened window(s) when returning to A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

```
function openWin() {
  w = window.open("","windowname"); // use the window name you gave it when you opened it
  if (w && !w.closed) ...
}
```