# Javascript Window.Open how to obtain the opened child window from a different page

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project where i can open a child window anywhere within the site, to display order details relating to the logged in user. On one of the pages i need to refresh the data when the window is closed. I have worked out how to refresh the data if the window is closed and the window was opened on that page. The issue i am having is if the child window was opened on a different page and the user navigated to the page that requires it to refresh once the window is shut, i need to obtain the reference to the open child window so i can call my javascript that causes the data to refresh, if the child window is shut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue i was having using the code from the following link

[Obtain reference to existing browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404877/obtain-reference-to-existing-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

First  its seen little bit tricky..
you declare some ajax function to send information to server whether child window opened or not.. if child window opened then refresh page.

for E.g .
 -> assume that user opened 2 same page In different tabs1 and tab2. 
 -> user opened opened  popup window on tab2 and add/change some information..
 -> tab2 content refresh as per ur event.
 you should also send a one flag to server with session id and tab1 continuous check is that any changes happed to server it will be refresh..

Answer (score 0):

You can open child window with javascript like this.

```
window.open("ChildWindowURL.aspx?source=windowA");
```

In the Page_Load of child, you can get the source.

```
string action = Request.QueryString["source"];
```

You can send this value to client side with hidden value, and when child window is closed, do refresh or what you need.